# Regarding swing containers

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout, grid-layout

I was doing a research, I have the below application in that we have the following swing layout..

[image]

Now the thing is that this same ting I want to develop I was using swing designer of google framework ..

[image]

Please advise me what container layout and extras other things do I need t build this same forat through swing designer and I aslo later want to customize it.

Comment: I guess your first starting point is [HOW TO CREATE TRANSLUCENT AND SHAPED WINDOWS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, your problem is resizing two buttons equally? Well, I'd use [Mig Layout](http://miglayout.com/), create two columns, that will scale 50% each.

Comment: *"will scale 50% each"*  `GridLayout` can do that, I guess `GridBagLayout` could do it as well, with the right weights and layout constraints.